# Spring forms controller generalization

Tags: java, forms, spring, controller

When making controller for spring mvc application I have to specify
a new method every time I want to pass a new class instances from spring forms:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String mainPost(@Valid MyClass myClass, 
        BindingResult result, Model model) {
    // do the same stuff each time here
}
```

So I need to write a method for every possible MyClass in my application
that can be passed to controller, but all these methods do absolutely the same stuff
(they check for errors and pass this object to service layer).

How can I merge all this methods in one?
I believe that there is some solution similar to the following (that doesn't work):

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public <T> String mainPost(@Valid T myObject, 
        BindingResult result, Model model) {
    // check errors and pass the object myObject to a service layer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have generic controller methods, but you can create generic controller:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T> {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String mainPost(@Valid T myObject,
          BindingResult result, Model model) { ... } 
}

@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/myclass")
public class MyClassController extends AbstractController<MyClass> { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, it's much more simple, but I hope there is some way to write controller that allows you not to add more controller code when you add some new class to your model. When I use such an AbstractController I still need to add new controller class when I add new class into model.

Comment: @tsds: If your generic method uses the same URL mapping for different model classes, how would it know which one should it bind?

Comment: Every spring form has commandName parameter, so when you post data spring constructs an instance of that class (specified in this parameter), I think that this information would be enough for controller but I'm not very confident about it.